# How to create an .img file from a docker .tar folder

Tags: image, docker, cluster-computing

I am a relatively new user with docker, and I'm having trouble grasping the workflow of Docker. Essentially, I have a Docker Image that I am trying to place/store locally as an .img file, but I have no idea how to get there and cannot find clear documentation on how to do so.

I have this image in a .tar file already from using the "docker save" command, but in order to use it in my cluster's preexisting system, I need to convert that into an .img file that I can store anywhere.

Hopefully, this makes sense. Very sorry if this is a simple fix but would appreciate any help!

Comment: What is a .img file?  Is there a particular cluster orchestrator you’re using (Docker Swarm, Kubernetes)?  Have you researched the various options for private Docker image registries?

Answer (score 0):

Docker image is composed of layers which are .tar files. You can store images in Docker registries (either public or private). There is no such thing as .img file for docker images. When you upload image you actually push those .tar files.

[Docker Registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/#what-it-is)